# Efficiently associating a single value with an interval

Tags: python, collections

I've got a situation where I've got finer time granularity than I do position granularity. Let's say that I'm measuring position at 10 Hz, but am making other measurements at 100 Hz. I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a clever/efficient way of associating a position with a time interval? That is, given a time that falls within that interval the lookup would return an appropriate position. It may just be that a straightforward implementation involving a list of tuples (start_time, end_time, position) and looping won't be disastrous, but I'm curious to know how other people have dealt with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to store a sorted list of the dictionary keys (ie. the time values) and use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) library to find the appropriate key given an intermediate value

```
positions = {10: (1, 30), 20: (20, 30), 30: (40, 40)}

# In practice, you want to create and add to this list 
# the same time you add keys and values to the positions dictionary.
times = sorted(positions.keys())

t = 23
# Get the nearest time values (higher and lower)
# Test them both to see which is closer (ie. whether we
# should round up or down)
index = bisect.bisect(times, t)
l_i = max(index - 1, 0)
r_i = min(index, len(times) - 1)
if abs(times[l_i] - t) < abs(times[r_i] - t):
    t_nearest = times[l_i]
else:
    t_nearest = times[r_i]

position = positions[t_nearest]
```

Whenever you add a new `time: position` value to the positions dictionary, make sure to add the time key to the `times` sorted list.  You can use bisect to insert it at the right position

```
bisect.insort(times, 25)
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Thomas-Lotze - you broke the logjam in my thinking about the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a data structure that maps interval start or end points to positions. In order to compute the interval you need to look up, either do some appropriate rounding on the time value in question (if the intervals can be considered regular enough for that), or use the `bisect` module to look up the closest start or end point in the list of all occurring intervals.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds promising. I haven't used bisect yet, so I'll have a look. Your comment also made me realize that I'd been imposing a restraint on myself that I didn't need to. That is, I'd been imagining position[0] being tied to 'interval[0]'.  However, I'd be fine with position[0] being associated with [start[0], start[0] + .5 * interval], position[1] being associated with [start[1] - .5*interval, start[1] + .5*interval], etc.